# pgfgantt - Gantt chart with two highlighted vertical lines with labels

Tags: pgfgantt

"today" allows us to create one highlighted vertical line with a label.
But how can I create more than one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please clarify better your question, perhaps posting a [minimal (non) working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to start with?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163521/1952